# Imagemagick not found by other apps, but needs to be updated in any case. How best to remove and install v7-

Tags: software-installation, imagemagick, version, uninstall

I am running Mint 21.1 64 bit. I believe that Imagemagick v6.. was installed via the 'synaptic package manager'.

I now require Imagemagick **v7**, to dovetail with another app that will not work with v6 or lower.

Imagemagick v7 **isn't** available synaptically, or from the Mint *'Software Manager'*. So, it seems that I would need to install from one of the RPM packages. None of the RPM packages seem to be customized for Mint / Ubuntu. Given all that, What is the best way to remove the old components of v6 and install the new ones, WITHOUT gorping my platform? I am concerned about removing the components because the PATH does not, currently, point to any of the 'imagemagick' components (which apparently have to be put in the PATH as separate entries), so that raises some doubt as to whether the initial installation of v6 was as complete and tidy as it should have been (and so reversing the installation of v6 might be a disaster).

EDIT:
Because I have Scribus installed, GraphicsMagick is also installed because Scribus is dependent upon GraphicsMagick . Does anybody know if conflicts arise because both are present? There just seems to be too much "Magick" going on here...apparently Imagemagick and 'Magick' are terms used interchangeably (at least in some contexts) and GraphicsMagick is a branch from ImageMagick, but that was two full versions back and there is no cooperation between the teams presently. It is hard to parse and comprehend how these might complicate the solution...

Comment: Does the other app work with GraphicsMagick instead of ImageMagick?

Comment: No matter what you do, if you're removing your current version of imagemagick, you will break any application that links against imagemagick. Which involves a lot of script language runtimes, graphics editors, thumbnail generators, ... It might not be a feasible solution at all! In which way does the other application (maybe tell us which?) require V7?

Comment: And: how did you install V6? If it was installed though package management, the installation is probably fine.

Comment: I don't recall exactly, but I think that Imagemagick was installed from the Synaptic Package Manager. Its installation may have been triggered as a dependency, from some other installation. In any case, its presence does show up in the Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: Does anybody know if it is possible to have both v6 and v7 installed on the same platform?

Comment: How about running v7 inside `docker`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74032739/2836621